# How can I redirect 301 all error pages to sub folder?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I want to redirect 301 with htaccess file my broken URLs. What do I mean? If visitor come to this link: http://mydomain.com/blablablablablablablabla34234234.php he probably will get an 404 error so I want my "404 page" will be in sub folder. like this:
http://mydomain.com/somenonpage.php to http://mydomain.com/sub/somenonpage.php
http://mydomain.com/blablablablabla to http://mydomain.com/sub/blablablablabla
etc.

Comment: Can you explain a little clearer, maybe show the content of your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a custom 404 page you do not do a 301 Redirect, 301 is to redirect an old link to a new URL. Say you had a popular post but decided to change the url for SEO reasons but the old url was heavily backlinked. You would then use a 301 to make sure that those backlinks got associated with your new url.

To make a custom 404 all you need to do is edit your http.conf file and add a path to your custom 404 page. By default I think the file belongs in your root directory named `404.html`.

If you need the fileto have a different name or location you can edit the file path at the line beginning line `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html`.

Comment: But I dont want to redirect all 404 pages to one page.
I want to redirect the current page to sub folder, like that:
http://mydomain.com/somenonpage.php to http://mydomain.com/sub/somenonpage.php
http://mydomain.com/blablablablabla to http://mydomain.com/sub/blablablablabla
etc.